# running /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt as nagios user does not return the correct result

Tags: 12.04, apt, nagios3, nrpe

I have two servers, both running 12.04 server, and nagios-nrpe-server.

On both, I have configured the command `check_apt`, which runs `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt`.

On both, nagios-nrpe-server is configured to run as the `nagios` user.

Unfortunately, on one of the servers, I always receive an OK signal with 0 updates when, from a different server, I run `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H hostname -c check_apt`, despite there being updates.

I followed this through and noticed that on one server, `check_apt` runs as the `nagios` user and does indeed return with a warning or critical when required.

The other, problematic server, always says 0 updates required when run as the nagios user, but will always give the correct response when run as `root`.

On this problematic server, I also note that the MOTD always displays the wrong number of packages. It's as if neither commands are allowed to access the number of updates for a server.

Comment: What groups are these two Nagios users in?

Comment: su to the nagios user and try and run it manually?

Comment: 1) the nagios users are only in 1 group: nagios

Comment: 2) SUing yeilds the same results. One server works fine, the other does not.

Comment: @jrg making sure you got the OP's reply.  SuperMatt: Unless you include 'at' (@) and the users name, they usually won't get your comment.

Comment: @SuperMatt ok, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo` to run this command as `nagios` user. `nagios` user has to execute this command:

```
nagios  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt
```